# Redundant Pulling Of Data Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny application where I am importing data from my mongo DB. I am using shinymanager package for authentication.

The problem I am having is, the data is imported once before the user logs in and a second time after the user logs in.

The goal is to only pull the data set in once. This can be either before or after the user logs in.

gloabl.R

```
urlm = #"myMongoUrl"

df.orats = mongo(collection = "df.orats", db = "test", url = urlm, verbose = T)
df.finalVol = mongo(collection = "df.finalVol", db = "test", url = urlm, verbose = T)
df.pass = mongo(collection  = "df.pass", db = "test", url = urlm, verbose = T)
```

Server.R

```
function(input, output, session) {

secure_server(check_credentials = check_credentials(z))


    df.f = df.orats$find()
    df.h = df.finalVol$find()

    df.new = reactive({
      df.h %>% filter(Price, Ivol)
    })

   }
```

As you can see, the 2 data sets were imported twice. 
[image]

What I am looking for is something like req(check_credentials).

I have tried using.

```
observerEvent(req(check_credentials(z),{
df.f = df.orats$find()
    df.h = df.finalVol$find()

    df.new = reactive({
      df.h %>% filter(Price, Ivol)
    })
})
```

But the data is still imported twice.
Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Lastly here is a picture for more intuition.
[image]

[image]

Below is code for @Siddharth Arthi as he is giving me a hand. I have added a line of code to print the results. As you can see the results are false before and after authentication.

```
secure_server(check_credentials = check_credentials(z))

   returns <- check_credentials(z)
    observe({print(returns("results")[1])})
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the check_credentials() function as the event, use the returned **result** from the function to confirm user authentication and fetch data from Mongo.

An updated snippet from your original code:

```
returns <- check_credentials(z)

observeEvent(returns(result)[1],{
if(returns(result)[1]){
df.f = df.orats$find()
    df.h = df.finalVol$find()

    df.new = reactive({
      df.h %>% filter(Price, Ivol)
    })
}
})
```

**observeEvent** would run any time the passed value gets updated. However, in our case, it needs to run once, say after the user logs in. The above snippet would satisfy this condition. Hope this helps!

**Edit:** Update based on inputs from Jordan.

```
userAuth <- secure_server(check_credentials = check_credentials(z))

observeEvent(userAuth$user,{

df.f = df.orats$find()
    df.h = df.finalVol$find()

    df.new = reactive({
      df.h %>% filter(Price, Ivol)
    })

})
```

By default `secure_server` function returns the username entered as a list when the authentication is successful. We can try using that as a trigger to process our data. Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Hey Siddharth! thanks for the input. However, I am having some trouble with your code. I changed "observerEvent" to "observeEvent" and I changed "returns$result" to  "returns(result)[1]" as returns is an environment. returns(result)[1] is False before and after verification for some reason. I was expecting it to turn to true

Comment: Apologies. Updated my answer. Returned result need to be True for the validation to be success. Sounds different. How do you check the users authentication result in your application?

Comment: I added a snippet at the bottom of the original post for you to see.

Comment: you're a beauty. Thanks!